# Creating a new library in Zend?

Tags: php, zend-framework

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to indicate zend framework where my custom classes are](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2495606/how-to-indicate-zend-framework-where-my-custom-classes-are)

I'm trying to create a new library in Zend. I have a few classes in my new library dir (/library/my-lib)

When I try to create a object from a class in my new library I get a "class not found" found.

Do I need to set something up in my application.ini?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add custom class (or custom library) one can use zend framework's autoloader namespaces.

Add the below line in application.ini file

```
autoloaderNamespaces.custom = "Custom_"
```

OR

```
autoloaderNamespaces[] = "Custom_"
```

Even this:

```
autoloaderNamespaces.extension[] = "Custom_"
```

Is said to work.

Then it should find your libs. Btw this is a copy of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2495606/how-to-indicate-zend-framework-where-my-custom-classes-are)

And like Zdenek Machek said change the name to be more standard with how zf names things. Ie: MyLib is a much better name then my-lib.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, add to application.ini

> autoloaderNamespaces.extension[] = "MyLib_"

I would suggest also change my-lib to MyLib and class name then starts with MyLib_

Comment: Very good suggestion about MyLib.

Comment: Are you sure extension is the right thing? The way I posted always works.

Comment: It works, but in your case autoloaderNamespaces[] might be enough