# How to register customized library in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework, namespaces

I have created my own library in Zend framework for some custom requirements. The Prefix that I am using in each class is "Dtd_". I would like to know that how would I register this so that it could become available globally.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to indicate zend framework where my custom classes are](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2495606/how-to-indicate-zend-framework-where-my-custom-classes-are)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple of methods to do this:

You can add namespaces in your application.ini file:

```
[production]
autoloaderNamespaces[] = "Dtd_"
```

Or, in your bootstrap:

```
protected function _initAutoloader()
{
    $autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
    $autoloader->registerNamespace("Dtd_");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You may use something like this

```
$loader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
$loader->registerNamespace('Dtd_');
```